# ¿Como restaurar el module dm-raid45 en lmde 2?

Tags: linux

¿Cómo restaurar el module dm-raid45 en linux mint debian edition 2? sale el mensaje:

> modprobe: module dm-raid45 not found in modules.dep

y no pasa de ahi.

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que adjuntaras los comandos y el contenido de los archivos que estes modificando, para asi, si alguien conoce una solucion, pueda ayudarte mas facilmente.

Comment: es cuando inicio sesion

Answer (score 0):

He hallado la solución en ochobitshacenunbyt.com. Abrir la terminal y escribir:

```
sudo apt-get purge dmraid
sudo update-initramfs -u
```